# Superposition of images

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

I have 6 images, each consisting of an object of a single color and black background.

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

image3:

[image]

image4:

[image]

image5:

[image]

image6:

[image]

To superpose these image in sequence I did the following:

```
ImageAdd[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
```

The result is:

[image]

Does also another possibility exists to get the same result, since the speed is relatively slow when I use many and large images (originals are 4K)?

Comment: @Kuba and Szabolcs: The speed is relatively slow when I use many and large images (3000 originals each of 4K)?

Comment: What are your requirements on performance?  On my machine it takes 0.3 seconds to add up six 4K images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does also another possibility exists to get the same result, since the speed is relatively slow when I use many and large images (originals are 4K)?

I suspect that Mathematica's performance is close to the possible limit here.

Arithmetic operations on packed arrays are highly optimized in Mathematica.  They often use multiple cores (although apparently not `Total`) and I believe them to be close to as efficient as possible.

Let's test plain arithmetic:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

arr = Table[RandomReal[1, {2160, 3840, 3}], {6}];

Total[arr]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.423801, Null} *)
```

Now let's compare with images:

```
imgs = Table[RandomImage[1, {3840, 2160}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], {6}];

img = ImageAdd @@ imgs; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.320025, Null} *)
```

You can see that `ImageAdd` is doing quite well.

Looking at my process monitor, `Total` doesn't use multiple cores, `ImageAdd` does.

These are all Real type images (64-bit floating point).  Let us try converting to Byte type (8-bit), which should give a considerable speedup.

```
imgs = Image[#, "Byte"] & /@ imgs;

img = ImageAdd @@ imgs; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.081113, Null} *)
```

If you import JPEGs from disk, you should get Byte type images.  Verify this using [`ImageType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageType.html).  Try to keep your images in this format for better performance.

An important difference between Real and Byte that you should be aware: Real doesn't clip, Byte does.  I.e. 0.6+0.6 is 1.2 in a Real image, but it's only 1.0 (internally 255) in a Byte type image because the Byte type has a hard upper limit.

**Summary:** **I doubt that there's anything we can do within Mathematica to speed `ImageAdd` up.   It already performs very well.**

It may be possible to create a slightly faster low-level implementation in principle, but I'm sure that a dramatic speedup is plainly impossible.  4K images are large and it is slow to work with them.

Comment: @mrz Keep in mind that *displaying* the result may take much longer than computing it.  `img = ImageAdd[...];` will finish faster than the same without the semicolon.